# Characteristic vector of zero matrix

Tags: matrices

Can we talk about characteristic vector of a zero matrix? If yes, What is the characteristic vector of the zero matrix?

Comment: what is a *characteristic vector*?

Answer (score 1):

A “characteristic vector”, or “eigenvector”, $v$ corresponding to a given eigenvalue $\lambda$ of matrix $A$ is a vector such that $Av= \lambda v$.  Since the 0 matrix times **any** vector is the 0 vector, the only eigenvalue is 0 and **every** non-zero vector is a characteristic vector.

Comment: Well, every non-zero vector.

Comment: I understand that the usual definition of "eigenvector" requires that it be non-zero.  There is a (perhaps very small) group of people who would prefer to include the 0 vector as an "eigenvector" so that we can, for example, say that "the set of all eigenvectors corresponding to a given eigenvector form a subspace" rather than having to say ""the set of all eigenvectors corresponding to a given eigenvector, together with the 0 vector, form a subspace".  Of course the definition of "eigenvalue" requires that there exist a **non-zero** vector, v, such that $Av= \lambda v$.

Comment: You eventually have to call the zero vector out as an exception somewhere. It may as well be up front in the definition of eigenvector.

Answer (score 0):

Any basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (orthonormal ones are preferable) happen to be a basis of eigenvectors for the $n \times n$ zero matrix. For example, for the zero matrix \begin{bmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0\\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix} any of the following matrices (whose columns make a basis of $\mathbb{R}^4$) $$\begin{bmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\ 0&1&0&0\\ 0&0&1&0\\ 0&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} \quad\quad \begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&-1&-1\\ 1&1&-1&-1\\ 1&0&2&-1\\ 1&0&0&3 \end{bmatrix} \quad\quad \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{bmatrix} 1&-1&-1&-1\\ 1&1&0&0\\ 1&0&1&0\\ 1&0&0&1 \end{bmatrix}$$ will work.

Comment: A basis is not a basis change matrix. And all bases are bases of eigenvectors for the zero matrix (just like for any scalar matrix).

Comment: Why are you insisting that these must be orthonormal?